# How to change vector to a regular array?

Tags: c++

I have a working function that changes an integer to an array of a vector.
I want to change it to a regular array without a vector.

the array will be multidimensional

```
int a = 12345;

int v[4][4]
{
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0 }
};

int main()
{
    getArray(a, v[2]);

    cout << v[0] << v[1] << v[2] << v[3] << v[4] << " ";
}
```

This is what I have now but it only works with the vector

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void getArray(T1& setData, T2& getArray)
{
    for (; setData > 0;)
    {
        getArray.emplace(getArray.begin(), setData % 10);
        setData /= 10;
    }
}

int a = 12345;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    getArray(a, v);

    cout << v[0] << v[1] << v[2] << v[3] << v[4] << " ";

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: why not use `string`?

Comment: and what you really want? Your first script simply makes no sense, and second script is unrelated to first.

Comment: Can you have a function name the same as a parameter name? Is this one of those 'new' C++ features?

Comment: @Adrian overloading a function name with a variable name is fine in C++ afaik

Comment: @Ayxan So it would seem (just checked in my MSVC). Never occurred to me that you could do that, or would want to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done. Just use `=` instead of `emplace` and also the size is now fixed because we are using arrays. So you an array of 5 `int`s, not 4:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T1, typename T2, auto sz>
void getArray(T1& setData, T2 (&arr)[sz]) {
  for (auto i = sz - 1; setData > 0; setData /= 10, --i) {
    arr[i] = setData % 10;
  }
}

int a = 12345;
int v[4][5]{};

int main() {
  getArray(a, v[2]);

  std::cout << v[2][0] << v[2][1] << v[2][2] << v[2][3] << v[2][4] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Your solution suits me thanks, I'm a little confused with this part. `auto i = sz - 1;`

Comment: My compiler also writes a missing `sz` template instance
  `getArray(a, v[2]);`

Comment: @Nigan `i = sz - 1;` because `sz - 1` is the index of the last element.

Comment: Instead of `auto`, it’s better to write `size_t sz`or `int`

Comment: By the way, I did not know that it is possible to do this, what does it mean?
`typename T2, auto sz>` Does the compiler perceive this as one element, or how does it work?

Comment: @Nigan it is called a non-type template parameter. Learn more about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), you could write a generic template function, as it uses the iterators of the container. Which might be a best suit for your case, as you want to pass either `std::vector` or a *normal array*.

However, `strSetData` also needs to be iterable, for which I had to convert it to a `std::string`. If that affordable, here you go. **([See live online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ei4r5h06VwOExWmJ))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>    // std::to_string
#include <algorithm> // std::transform
#include <iterator>  // std::begin, std::end

template <typename Iterator>
void getArray(const std::string& strArr, 
                    Iterator arrBeginIter)
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ---> pass the begin iterator, instead of the container
{
    std::transform(std::cbegin(strArr), std::cend(strArr), arrBeginIter,
        [](const char element) ->int { return element - '0'; }
    );
}

int main()
{
    int a = 12345;
    const std::string strSetData{ std::to_string(a) };
    {
        std::vector<int> v(strSetData.size());
        getArray(strSetData, std::begin(v));
        std::cout << v[0] << v[1] << v[2] << v[3] << v[4] << " ";
    }
    {
        int v[5];
        getArray(strSetData, std::begin(v));
        std::cout << v[0] << v[1] << v[2] << v[3] << v[4] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but your option is harder for me, and I think it works slower.

Comment: @Nigan The only disadvantage what I see is this `const std::string strSetData{ std::to_string(a) };`. Other than that, it is same as what you do in your code. One advantage is that it works for all sequence containers and arrays,(more generic).  Well, "harder" will be someday "understandable" and "simple", therefore I leave it for the future reading and for future readers.